# Error while trying to integrate Twilio in .NET Core MVC Application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, return, twilio

I'm trying to integrate Twilio with my ASP.NET Core MVC Application but in the controller, I'm getting an error in my return statement.

> **Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Web.Mvc.ContentResult' to 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ContentResult'
> **

**Controller Code**

```
  using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Configuration;
using Twilio;
using Twilio.AspNet.Mvc;
using Twilio.Rest.Api.V2010.Account;
using Twilio.Types;
using Twilio.TwiML;

namespace TwilioTesting.Controllers
{
    public class SMSController : TwilioController
    {
        public ContentResult Index()
        {
            var accountSid = "AC12345678";
            var authToken = "12345678";

            TwilioClient.Init(accountSid, authToken);

            var to = new PhoneNumber("+92313887998");
            var from = new PhoneNumber("+19898980625");

            var message = MessageResource.Create(
                to: to,
                from: from,
                body: "Message from Kamran");
            return Content(message.Sid);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a `using Twilio.AspNet.Mvc;` import which is not for .NET Core & is for ASP.NET MVC. It is unexpectedly importing in `System.Web.Mvc.ContentResult` which is conflicting with the import of `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ContentResult`.

Remove it and replace it with `using Twilio;`.

Comment: Tried them but still the same error

Comment: @KamranBajwa please update your question with the updated code / errors

Comment: Please check now

Comment: It removes the error now but the app is not working now

Comment: @KamranBajwa please open a new question

Comment: Ermiya is correct that you're using the wrong NuGet package (`Twilio.AspNet.Mvc`). This package is for ASP.NET on .NET Framework. `Twilio.AspNet.Core` is the package for ASP.NET Core.
Although, you need neither for the code you're showing here. That library is used to respond to Twilio webhooks with the `TwilioController.TwiML` method, but you're not doing that in your snippet.
Instead of using `Twilio.AspNet.Mvc` or `Twilio.AspNet.Core`, use the `Twilio` package and inherit from `Controller` instead of `TwilioController`.

Comment: @Swimburger yes!  I tried to limit it to solving the compiler error 